# WinForms component crashes at LoadLibrary native call in Mono

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, mono, loadlibrary

We have a WinForms component that has been successfully used in Mono for many months by one of our customers. It seems, the component stopped working in the currently used version of Mono (the runtime is Mono 5, run on Ubuntu Linux 14 LTS).

The component throws an exception, and here is the top of the corresponding stack trace:

```
$ mono bin/Debug/ALMAViewer.exe
SendMessage (48234666, 0xd2, (nil), (nil))
SendMessage (48234668, 0xd2, (nil), (nil))
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: LoadLibraryA
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ComponentNamespace.NativeMethods:LoadLibrary (string)
```

I am not a guru in Mono, but if I understand this log right, Mono fails to load the WinAPI LoadLibrary function defined like this:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryA")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);
```

Does anybody tell me why this code stopped working in Mono and how to fix the problem? It looks like this platform no longer support ANSI API calls, and we need to use only the Unicode versions of WinAPi functions.

Comment: Are you allowed to tell which component it is?

Comment: Components with such Windows PInvoke should never be used on Mono and Linux. You have to get back to Windows, or completely replace the PInvoke code with Linux side PInvoke or managed equivalent, which Mono has an FAQ page.

Comment: @LexLi, the problem LoadLibrary call is used in a method that checks whether the app is rendered with visual styles. This code was written in the times of .NET 1.1, but it seems, it can be replaced with the native .NET [Application.RenderWithVisualStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.renderwithvisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) call. However, Application.RenderWithVisualStyles uses native OS calls inside too, though theoretically Mono may provide another 'safe' implementation of this member.